# How do you select every RectangleShape where tag=1?

Tags: vb.net

I need to change the location for every single RectangleShape in Form1. I already imported Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape. This is what I tried:

```
For Each Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape(Tag = 1) In Me
   Location.X -= 10
Next
```

But it comes up with the error that "'RectangleShape' is a type in 'PowerPacks' and cannot be used as an expression."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set `Strict On` and `Explicit On` in your project. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329

Comment: You probably need to trawl recursively through Me.Controls, and all the ControlIn.Controls in all of those subsequent Controls in order to drill down to the RectangleShapes you're looking for.

Comment: I tried strict on and explicit on, that didn't work. I'm a pretty new program so I don't really know what Controlln.Controls is